# Woocommerce cart page default to one

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, default

I have my woocommerce page to sell a single product. I need to to go to the cart page with default value of 1 in cart page, so that when users click

```
www.test.com/cart
```

it never says "cart is Empty"!
Any ways to do that?
What do I need to do? Any ideas?

Comment: I think it would be best to not auto-add an item, but rather redirect to the checkout when your 1 product is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *sounds* like you want to add a product to the user's cart even if they haven't actually added it themselves:

> So that when users click `www.test.com/cart` it never says "cart is Empty"

For what it's worth, I don't think that's a fantastic idea from a UX point of view (or pretty much any other). However, it is possible.

**Be warned:** This code is largely untested, and it's triggered to run on `init` (although it should only run each time the cart is visited). Generally, I would advise against this - but it should do what you want:

```
function vnm_addThingToCart() {

    //  Check we're not in admin

    if (!is_admin()) {

        //  Only do this on the cart page

        if (is_page('cart')) {
            global $woocommerce;

            //  You're only selling a single product, so let's make sure we're not going to add the same thing over and over

            $myProductID = 22;  //  Or whatever

            $productToAdd = get_product($myProductID);

            //  Make sure the product exists

            if ($productToAdd) {

                //  Make sure there's stock available

                $currentStock = $productToAdd->get_stock_quantity();

                if ($currentStock > 0) {

                    //  Add the product

                    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($myProductID);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}

add_action('init', 'vnm_addThingToCart');
```